# Do I need to add a gloss effect to an iTunesArtwork file?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunesartwork

For our app, we have a flat icon which we *do* want the OS to add a gloss effect to, so we have *not* set the UIPrerenderedIcon flag in our Info.plist.  We've got a larger version for our iTunesArtwork file, which is a PNG.  Do we need to add a gloss effect to the iTunesArtwork ourselves, or will the app store do it for us?

Answer (score 1):

The app store will do it for you, you don't need to apply the gloss.

Answer (score -1):

Your iTunesArtwork will get the gloss effect automatically if you set the UIPrerenderedIcon flag.

Comment: No, it's the other way round: to get the gloss effect you must NOT set the UIPrerenderedIcon flag. Setting the flag means "I add the gloss myself". (For those who wondered: this flag is set if you check the "Prerendered" check box next to the app icons in the Target Summary settings)

Comment: yes, you are right, I actually wanted to say that you have to set this flag accordingly. Thanks for the correction.